# API to inspect task queue length from app engine flex?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

Is there an API to inspect a task queue's backlog from within app engine flex? App Engine Standard has the com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.Queue.fetchStatistics API but that seems to fail in App Engine Flex with error: 
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call taskqueue.FetchQueueStats in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Task Queue API [was deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/rest) and is currently only available for App Engine Standard 1st generation runtime.

For App Engine Flex, Standard 2nd gen and other applications, you should use the [Cloud Tasks API](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues/get)